# Android Maps Projection fromScreenLocation returns wrong geo position

Tags: android, location, maps, point

The Google Map provides over its projection a method, which converts Point to Geo Position.

If I pass e.x. Point p = new Point(-1000,1000), I get a position like -89.3425,140.0345. The point is outside the visible region but I could not found any information if that method has a limitation to the current visible region.

Has someone a source code or more information about that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a `Rect` with the size of your `MapView` and use `Rect.contains(x,y)` to check if the given point is inside the `MapView`

Remember:

> The screen location is specified in screen pixels (not display pixels)
>   relative to the top left of the map (not the top left of the whole
>   screen).